# Calling a Module Function By Reference

Tags: perl, dynamic, module, subroutine

I am looking at building a dispatch table for calling a number of Perl modules that I wrote.

As an example, if I have a package called `Hello.pm` with a simple function `hello()` in it, I would like to get a code reference to this function.

The following does not work:

```
my $code_ref=\&Hello->hello();
$code_ref->();
```

But if the function hello is exported from the package, then the following works:

```
my code_ref=\&hello;
code_ref->();
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax for the first case? Or is this simply not possible?

In the end, I would like to populate a hash table with all my code references.

##### Thanks for All Answers

The correct invocation as pointed out by several answers is:

```
my $code_ref=\&Hello::hello;
$code_ref->();
```

I have some 10 modules in 10 different files that I would like to load in a dispatch table.
This makes it easier for me to have the configuration loaded as data, and separate from code.
This allows me to load additional modules in a testbench without modifying my code-simply modify the configuration file.  Mark Dominus, author of Higher Order Perl, has some nice examples on this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I finally figured out how to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to refer to the hello sub in the Hello module, then call it, use:

```
my $code_ref = \&Hello::hello;
$code_ref->();
```

If you want to call a method named "hello" in Hello, you can do it like this:

```
my $method = "hello";
Hello->$method();
```

Comment: The :: did not work. After all, this is equivalent to ->.  I am just looking at understanding how to establish a reference to a function in a module when there is no export of the function name.

Comment: The `->` in `Foo->bar()' is equivalent to `Foo::bar('Foo')`. THe `->` means that whatever is in front of it (like an object or a class name) will be passed to the sub that is being called as the first argument. With `Foo::bar()`, that is not the case.

Comment: $code_ref is a reference to a sub, so the -> here is dereferencing it. It's not the same as the arrow used for method calls. So `$code_ref->()` is the same as `&{$code_ref}()`, where the & is being used to dereference it.

Comment: Okay! I see my typo. I had the () after hello. The parenthesis should not have been there as parenthesis here imply a function call.

Comment: And I cannot use -> as this is a method invocation as pointed. The :: defines the scope and this is the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

`\&NAME` takes a reference to a sub. `Hello->hello()` is not a sub name. As an expression, it would be a method call.

To get a reference to a method, use `can`.

```
my $method_ref = Hello->can('hello');
```

That will search the inheritance tree if necessary. Now that you have a reference to the right method, you can call it:

```
Hello->$method_ref()
  -or-
$method_ref->('Hello')
```

If you need a callback that can't call the method properly, you'll need to create a callback that does.

```
my $code_ref = sub { Hello->hello(@_) };
```

Here's what it looks like fully dynamic:

```
my $pkg         = 'Hello';  # Also works with object!
my $method_name = 'hello';
my $method_ref  = $pkg->can($method_name);

my $callback = sub { $pkg->$method_ref(@_) };
```

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want is

```
my $code_ref = \&hello;
$code_ref->();
```

Comment: Other than the missing dollar signs (which must be typos, since the code would not even compile without them), this is exactly what the OP already _has_.

Comment: There are no dollar signs needed here. We are simply establishing a reference to a function that was exported by the Hello Module.The above code works. My simple question question is why cannot I establish a reference to Hello->hello() directory.